# Question from Katok and Hasselblat (proof for Birkhoff Ergodic Theorem)

Tags: measure-theory, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

I am reading the specific proof of Birkhoff ergodic theorem given in Katok and Hasselblat's book.

They work with a measure preserving map $T:X\rightarrow X$ on a probability space $(X, \mathcal{B}, \mu)$. They choose $\varphi \in L^1(\mu)$ and as ususal the goal is to show
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}\varphi(T^k(x))
$$
exists for almost every $x$.

The proof starts as something like what follows.

- Let $\mathcal{I}:= \{A \in \mathcal{B}:\ T^{-1}(A) = A\}$. This defines a $\sigma$-algebra for itself which they call the invariant $\sigma$-algebra.
- They proceed by defining the conditional expectation $f_{\mathcal{I}} := \mathbb{E}[f|\mathcal{I}]$. That is, let $\nu(A) := \int_A f\ d\mu$ be a measure on $\mathcal{I}$. Also restrict $\mu$ on $\mathcal{I}$ and denote it by $\mu'$. Then $f_{\mathcal{I}} := d\nu/d\mu'$ is given by Radon-Nikodym.
- Next they define $F_n := \max_{k \le n} \sum_{i = 1}^{k - 1} f\circ T^i$ and claim that
  $$
      \limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}(f \circ T^k)/n \le \limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty} F_n/n \le 0
  $$
  holds if and only if $A:=\{x \in X: F_n(x) \rightarrow \infty \} \in \mathcal{I}$.

**Why is this true?**

**In general, if you know how to explain the proof in a little bit less messier way, I would  highly appreciate it!**

Comment: It is unclear how $A$ relates to the inequality you wrote. Do they address this before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you ask both about one specific part of the proof and the proof in general, I'll try to rewrite the proof in a more verbose fashion, paying specific attention to the part you asked about. **I've bolded the parts that are relevant to your specific "Why is this true?" question.** Hopefully this response is somewhat helpful! (It was at least a good exercise for *me*.)

**The main comment I want to make regarding your "Why is this true?" question is that your post has a bit of confusion about the claim KH are making. In particular, KH are making two separate claims:**

1. **Your inequality chain holds whenever $x \notin A$, and**
2. **$A \in \mathcal{I}$.**

I'll get to elaborating on both of these.
The idea of the proof is to show specifically that the time averages of $\varphi$ converge to the conditional expectation $\varphi_{\mathcal{I}}$. We'll do this by estimating the $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ of these time averages; a very slick lemma allows us to do both of these with the same argument. The lemma is as follows:

**Lemma.** Let $f \in L^1(\mu)$ satisfy $f_{\mathcal{I}} < 0$. Then $\limsup_{n \to \infty} \tfrac{1}{n} \sum_{k = 0}^{n-1} f \circ T^k(x) \leq 0$ for $\mu$-a.e. $x$.

*Proof.* **[Part 1 of your "Why is this true".]** Consider the max-partial-sums of $f$,
$$
  F_n(x) = \max_{1 \leq k \leq n} \sum_{i = 0}^{k-1} f \circ T^k(x).
$$
Note that for every $x$, the sequence $F_n(x)$ is nondecreasing. We let $A = \lbrace x : F_n(x) \to \infty \rbrace$. Then for $x \notin A$ there exists some $C(x)$ such that $F_n(x) \leq C(x)$ for all $n$, and so
$$
  \tfrac{1}{n} \sum_{k = 0}^{n-1} f \circ T^k(x) \leq \frac{1}{n}F_n(x) \leq \frac{1}{n} C(x) \to 0, 
$$
from which the conclusion of the lemma follows. **[This is the justification for the inequality chain part of your question.]**

So it suffices to show $\mu(A) = 0$.

We note, for later use, that the max-partial-sum functions $F_n$ satisfy
\begin{equation} \tag{1}
  F_{n+1}(x) = \begin{cases} 
     f(x) + F_n(Tx) & \text{if } F_n(Tx) \geq 0 \\
     f(x) & \text{if } F_n(Tx) < 0.
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}
(The second case happens if the max in $F_{n+1}(x)$ happens for $k = 1$, and the first case happens otherwise.)

**Subclaim.** $A \in \mathcal{I}$. **[This is the other part of your direct question.]**

*Proof of subclaim.*
We must show $T^{-1}(A) = A$, so show both inclusions:

- If $x \in T^{-1}(A)$, then $Tx \in A$, so for large enough $n$, $F_n(Tx)$ is positive, and so $F_{n+1}(x) = f(x) + F_n(Tx)$, which shows that $x \in A$.
- If $x \in A$, then $F_{n+1}(x)$ is unbounded, so for large enough $n$, $F_n(Tx)$ must be positive (otherwise we would have $F_{n+1}(x) = f(x)$ for an infinite subsequence). So $F_n(Tx) = F_{n+1}(x) - f(x)$ for large enough $n$, which shows $Tx \in A$, i.e., $x \in T^{-1}(A)$. $\square$

Back to the proof of the lemma. From our max-partial-sum relation $(1)$ we have
$$
  F_{n+1} - F_n \circ T = f - \min \lbrace 0, F_n \circ T \rbrace.
$$
For $x \in A$, the expression $F_n \circ T(x)$ blows up, so for each $x$ the minimum in this expression is eventually $0$ for large enough $n$. That is, $F_{n+1} - F_n \circ T$ converges pointwise to $f$ from above on $A$. By the monotone convergence theorem (or the dominated convergence theorem),
$$
  \int_A (F_{n+1} - F_n \circ T ) \, d\mu \to \int_A f \, d \mu.
$$
Note though that
$$
 \int_A (F_n \circ T ) \, d\mu = \int_{T^{-1}(A)} F_n \, d \mu = \int_A F_n \, d\mu
$$
since $A \in \mathcal{I}$, and hence (since $F_{n+1} - F_n$ is clearly nonnegative),
$$
  \int_A (F_{n+1} - F_n \circ T ) \, d\mu \geq 0.
$$
On the other hand, again using $A \in \mathcal{I}$ (and by the definition of conditional expectation),
$$
  \int_A f \, d\mu = \int_A f_{\mathcal{I}} \, d\mu.
$$
Putting these together, we conclude
$$
  \int_A f_{\mathcal{I}} \, d\mu \geq 0,
$$
which forces $\mu(A) = 0$ since $f_{\mathcal{I}} < 0$ by hypothesis. This proves the lemma. $\square$

**Proof of Birkhoff Ergodic Theorem.**

Apply the lemma to $f = \varphi - \varphi_{\mathcal{I}} - \varepsilon$ to conclude that for $\mu$-a.e. $x$,
$$
 \limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (\varphi - \varphi_{\mathcal{I}} - \varepsilon) (T^k x) \leq 0.
$$
Noting that $\varphi_{\mathcal{I}} \circ T = \varphi_{\mathcal{I}}$, this is
$$
  \limsup_{n \to \infty} \left( \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \varphi \circ T^k (x)\right) - \varphi_{\mathcal{I}}(x) - \varepsilon \leq 0,
$$
which shows
$$\
\limsup_{n \to \infty} \tfrac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \varphi \circ T^k \leq \varphi_{\mathcal{I}} + \varepsilon
$$
almost everywhere. Similarly, applying the lemma to $f = -\varphi + \varphi_{\mathcal{I}} - \varepsilon$ shows that
$$
\liminf_{n \to \infty} \tfrac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \varphi \circ T^k \geq \varphi_{\mathcal{I}} - \varepsilon
$$
almost everywhere, which proves the theorem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I assumed the "off" in the book is a typo and they meant "iff" a the abbreviation for "if and only if". I'm no longer confused but I must say the way they wrote that proof is very vaugue. Thanks again for clarification!